# Evaluating improper integrals with characteristics of both type I and type II

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Integrating improper integrals constitute of integrating functions

1) over an infinite integral

2) over an interval where f has a discontinuity.

Namely, integrals type I and type II, respectively. Generally, both types are solved in the same way using limits.

But consider the following integral:

$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}} dx$

In this case, I would proceed to set the integral $\int_0^t \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}} dx$ to $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to \infty}$. **However**, $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$ is discontinuous at $x=0$.

Why is this disregarded during integration??

Comment: Your comment about Type II is not correct.  If there is a discontinuity, the integration interval is subdivided at the point of discontinuity.  A discontinuity at an end point is ignored.  I suspect you will have trouble with your example as t becomes infinite - it diverges.

Comment: @herb yes, I know. I just didn't see it necessary to elaborate on type II as the key was the use of the limit :)

Comment: @herb what do you mean "a discontinuity at an end point is ignored"? I've never heard of that and disagree....

Comment: $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ is independent of f(x) for $x\lt a$, so whether or not it is continuous at a doesn't matter.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! Thank you :) But now I'm slightly confused as to why we have to set integrals to limits as t approaches b on the interval [a,b) if discontinuity on b doesn't matter? So it's not exactly ignored?

Comment: You need to set an integral to a limit when the integrand becomes infinite at the end point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think in that case you divide the integral in two because it have two cases of improper integral, so you make

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x}}+\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$$
so you study both part separated and in order to the original integral converge both integrals should converge. so it will be something like

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x}}=\lim_{t\to0^+}\int_{t}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$$

and

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x}}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{1}^{t}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$$

Comment: In general, subdivide into intervals where each interval has only one of those types at only one endpoint.

Comment: @cand Excellent!! _Infinite_ thanks! ;)